# how to call multiple functions in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
PS> 'abcjjadjjnamndabc' -replace 'abc', '$$' 
PS> 'abcjjadjjnamndabc' | foreach { $_ + " end of statement" }
```

I have above 2 statements which can run independently, but I want to do this action in one attempt.

I did try something like below, but syntax is failing.

```
PS> 'abcjjadjjnamndabc' | foreach { $_ + "end of statement" } |-replace 'abc', '',''
```

Comment: Wrap your pipeline in parenthesis to make it an expression with a return that `-replace` can work with: `('stringhere' | % {$_ + 'end'}) -replace 'abc'`

Comment: Alternatively: `'abcjjadjjnamndabc' | ForEach-Object { "$_ end of statement" -replace 'abc' }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that `-replace` is not a function, cmdlet or method. It's a [PowerShell Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6) and that means you cannot do `|-replace 'abc', ''` to pipe into it.

There are many ways you can combine these, the simplest is to swap the order and do the replace first:

```
'abcjjadjjnamndabc' -replace 'abc', '' | foreach { "$_ end of statement" }
```

Or to wrap the pipeline in parentheses, and do the replace on the result of that:

```
('abcjjadjjnamndabc' | foreach { "$_ end of statement" }) -replace 'abc', ''
```

Or (if you're not using regular expressions in the search/replace) to chain these similar methods:

```
'abcjjadjjnamndabc'.Replace('abc', '').ForEach({"$_ end of statement"})
```

Comment: Note the second argument to `-replace` is optional if your goal is to delete text.